# Three tables have a many to many relationship to one Table

Tags: database, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm wondering if this situation makes sense:
I have three Entities which are called(Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner). Now I want to have a relationship to the Entity Food. Each Entity(Breakf,Lunch,Dinner) exists of one or multiple food entitites. One Food Entity can exist only once in each entity of (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner) because it has an attribute amount. In this case I proably need a special Primary Key for each Food entity to provide the uniqueness of a food entity in an entity(Break,Lunch,Dinner).

Can somebody help to model the relationships? 
Is it simply a one to many relationship from each (Break,Lunch, Dinner) to Food?

Answer (score 1):

So the model depends on if you need to be able to scale the number of meals... If 3 meals is static then you could store this information in one table:

ID | food_name | breakfast_amount | Lunch_amount | Dinner_amount | insert_date

Comment: Since now I came up with something like that:

 FoodOverview (ID_Date PK, breakfastID FK, lunchID FK, dinnerID FK) ;
 Breakfast (ID PK, foodID FK);
 Lunch (ID PK, foodID FK);
 Dinner (ID PK, foodID FK);
 Food(foodID PK, amount INT, ....)

Comment: Yes you could have a "food table" a "meal table" and their primary keys could be fkeys in a third table like a junction table... in this case tho you will need to enforce the rule one meal can have many foods but not duplicate food per meal per insert_date... this will allow for scalablity as you can have N number of foods AND N number of meals... one table solution will not scale nicely...